# Bigquery internal error during copy job to move tables between datasets

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm currently migrating around 200 tables in Bigquery (BQ) from one dataset (FROM_DATASET) to another one (TO_DATASET). Each one of these tables has a _TABLE_SUFFIX corresponding to a date (I have three years of data for each table). Each suffix contains typically between 5 GB and 80 GB of data.

I'm doing this using a Python script that asks BQ, for each table, for each suffix, to run the following query:

```
-- example table=T_SOME_TABLE, suffix=20190915 
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `my-project.TO_DATASET.T_SOME_TABLE_20190915`
COPY `my-project.FROM_DATASET.T_SOME_TABLE_20190915`
```

Everything works except for three tables (and all their suffixes) where the copy job fails at each _TABLE_SUFFIX with this error:

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 4893854

Retrying the job after some time actually works but of course is slowing the process. Is there anyone who has an idea on what the problem might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Not 100% sure since the errors cannot be reproduced but `exception procedural` might be helpful. [BEGIN...EXCEPTION...END](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend)

Comment: Since this cannot be reproduce and might be an isolated case, you may contact https://cloud.google.com/support-hub to inspect your project and proceed with better troubleshooting steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that those three problematic tables were some legacy ones with lots of columns. In particular, the BQ GUI shows this warning for two of them:

> "Schema and preview are not displayed because the table has too many
> columns and may cause the BigQuery console to become unresponsive"

This was probably the issue.

In the end, I managed to migrate everything by implementing a backoff mechanism to retry failed jobs.